# Put the result of a select statement into specific sheet into Excel File

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, insert

How I could to put the result of a select statement into specific sheet into Excel File?

```
Insert into (Sheet1)ExcelFileLocation
Select col1, col2 from table1
where col1 = col2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389637/export-sql-query-data-to-excel

Comment: @Matt I can't find the specific sheet on that link

Answer (score 0):

You could use a "**linked server**" or could use **OPENROWSET** (ad hoc remote connection) to establish the connection to the worksheet

if you choose **OPENROWSET**, you need to activate it on MSSQL2005 and up:

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options',1
reconfigure
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries',1
reconfigure
```

finally here's the syntax to insert into excel in specific sheet:

```
insert into OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0','Excel 8.0;Database=C:\ExcelFileLocation\excel_file.xls;','SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]')
select col1, col2 from table1
 where col1 = col2
```

For more information, see [this link here](http://aartemiou.blogspot.ca/2009/02/manipulating-excel-97-2003-worksheets.html).