# How to export stored procedure data to Excel for dynamic columns in sql

Tags: sql

I have a stored procedure which returns values for dynamic column numbers. Suppose sometimes it returns value for 3 doctors so I have 3 columns, and the column name is doctor's name.

Sometime it returns output for 5 doctors etc...

I am done with my stored procedure but I want to export this data to Excel and I want to schedule this for a monthly basis.

Anyone has any idea how I can do this? Can I use a SSIS package for this or can I use SSRS?

Please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: what you mean with export to excel? send an excel file by email? save it on the same server sql is installed on? or on a different server? or maybe save the file on a user's workstation?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Export SQL query data to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389637/export-sql-query-data-to-excel)