# How to export data types from select query without MakeTable

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a select query(With joins on other tables), and want to export data types of columns to Excel or text. If I have table I used the "Generate script task". But in case of "select query" it is not suitable. I know that the simple solution is to make table of this query, but i have only read-only access to this database. How to do this without make-table ?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389637/export-sql-query-data-to-excel

Comment: in the link - Export SQL query data to Excel.   But my question is about data types

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
INTO #t
FROM [Your query]


DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(8000)


SELECT @sql = 'bcp "
 SELECT t.name as ''Data Type''
FROM tempdb.sys.columns c join sys.types t on c.system_type_id=t.system_type_id
WHERE [object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N''tempdb..#t''); " ' + 'queryout [Your Location]\[File Name].csv -c -t, -Usa -P[password] -S' + @@servername


EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @sql


DROP TABLE #t
```

Comment: Interesting method. You use temp table #t. But I have only read-only access in this base.

Comment: @ВиталийАщеулов that should not be a problem. Did you run the script ? what errors did you get ?

Comment: As long as a user can connect to a SQL Server instance, the user should be able to create temporary tables. The solution should not have any problem.