# Export SQL Query results in Excel and Send out in email

Tags: sql-server, excel, export-to-excel

I know this might be a repeated question but i could not find answers to this. I have SQL query that returns around 32K rows of data. I want a query to export this result into an excel file or pipe delimited text file and send out to a list of recipients everyday.

I am using SQL server Express edition 2012 version and unable to find a way to do this. Could you please help?

Regards

Saurabh

Comment: try these http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66126/how-to-export-data-from-sql-server-2008-to-excel-and-email-as-attachement https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/sending-query-results-to-excel-through-e-mail/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Export SQL query data to Excel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7389637/export-sql-query-data-to-excel)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help friends. One of my Developer friends told me that this can also be achieved easily through Talend.

For the time being, i have implemented this using Talend and scheduled the job using Task Scheduler.

Regards

Saurabh